# Multiply and append python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
   Colour   Type    Cost    Price   Type
0  Red      Car     3        5       Standard
1  Blue     Bike    6        7       Standard
2  Blue     Car     4        8       Standard
3  Green    Bike    6        9       Standard
4   Yellow  Bike    3        3       Standard
```

I then have an adjustment series, which I want to multiply the costs by and add to the bottom

```
Red   2
Blue  1
Green 3
```

So the output is:

```
   Colour   Type    Cost    Price   Type
0  Red      Car     3        5       Standard
1  Blue     Bike    6        7       Standard
2  Blue     Car     4        8       Standard
3  Green    Bike    6        9       Standard
4   Yellow  Bike    3        3       Standard
0  Red      Car     6        10       Adjusted
1  Blue     Bike    6        7       Adjusted
2  Blue     Car     4        8       Adjusted
3  Green    Bike    18        27       Adjusted
```

Is there an easy way of doing this as I'm a bit lost?

Comment: In the second dataframe; are the columns also called `Colour` and `Cost`?

Comment: good point. the second dataframe is actually just a series. I'll amend

Answer (score 2):

You can use `merge` and `concat`.

Adjustment dataframe:

```
   Colour   value
0   Red     2
1   Blue    1
2   Green   3
```

Then:

```
temp = df.merge(adj)

temp["Cost"] = temp["Cost"]*temp["value"]
temp["Price"] = temp["Price"]*temp["value"]
temp["Type.1"] = ["Adjusted"]*temp.shape[0]


pd.concat([df, temp.iloc[:,0:5]], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
    Colour  Type    Cost    Price   Type.1
0   Red     Car     3   5   Standard
1   Blue    Bike    6   7   Standard
2   Blue    Car     4   8   Standard
3   Green   Bike    6   9   Standard
4   Yellow  Bike    3   3   Standard
0   Red     Car     6   10  Adjusted
1   Blue    Bike    6   7   Adjusted
2   Blue    Car     4   8   Adjusted
3   Green   Bike    18  27  Adjusted
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the existing solutions for some variety:

Assuming the adjustment series is `s` as below:

```
s = pd.Series({'Red': 2, 'Blue': 1, 'Green': 3})
```

---

We can also `stack` the price columns and multiply, then `unstack` back and `concat`:

```
m = (df1.set_index(['Colour','Type'],append=True)[['Cost','Price']].stack()
        .mul(s,level=1).dropna().unstack().reset_index(['Colour','Type']))

pd.concat((df1,m),sort=False).fillna({'Type.1':'Adjusted'})
```

---

```
   Colour  Type  Cost  Price    Type.1
0     Red   Car   3.0    5.0  Standard
1    Blue  Bike   6.0    7.0  Standard
2    Blue   Car   4.0    8.0  Standard
3   Green  Bike   6.0    9.0  Standard
4  Yellow  Bike   3.0    3.0  Standard
0     Red   Car   6.0   10.0  Adjusted
1    Blue  Bike   6.0    7.0  Adjusted
2    Blue   Car   4.0    8.0  Adjusted
3   Green  Bike  18.0   27.0  Adjusted
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `assign`, `map`, `join` and `concat`

Note I've lowercased your second `Type` column to avoid the `.1` marker.

```
data = {'Red' :   2,
'Blue' : 1,
'Green' : 3}

new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df[["Colour", "Type"]]
        .join(
            df.select_dtypes("int64")
            .mul(df["Colour"].map(data), axis=0)
            .assign(type="adjusted")
        )
        .dropna(),
    ]
)
```

---

```
print(new_df)

   Colour  Type  Cost  Price      type
0     Red   Car   3.0    5.0  Standard
1    Blue  Bike   6.0    7.0  Standard
2    Blue   Car   4.0    8.0  Standard
3   Green  Bike   6.0    9.0  Standard
4  Yellow  Bike   3.0    3.0  Standard
0     Red   Car   6.0   10.0  adjusted
1    Blue  Bike   6.0    7.0  adjusted
2    Blue   Car   4.0    8.0  adjusted
3   Green  Bike  18.0   27.0  adjusted
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
In [2349]: df1 
Out[2349]: 
   Colour  Type  Cost  Price    Type.1
0     Red   Car     3      5  Standard
1    Blue  Bike     6      7  Standard
2    Blue   Car     4      8  Standard
3   Green  Bike     6      9  Standard
4  Yellow  Bike     3      3  Standard

In [2350]: df2  
Out[2350]: 
  Colour  Price
0    Red      2
1   Blue      1
2  Green      3

In [2341]: res = df1.merge(df2, on='Colour') 

In [2343]: res['Price'] = res.Price_x * res.Price_y    
In [2344]: res['Type.1'] = 'Adjusted'

In [2346]: res.drop(['Price_x','Price_y'], 1, inplace=True)

In [2351]: df1 = df1.append(res)

In [2352]: df1
Out[2352]: 
   Colour  Type  Cost  Price    Type.1
0     Red   Car     3      5  Standard
1    Blue  Bike     6      7  Standard
2    Blue   Car     4      8  Standard
3   Green  Bike     6      9  Standard
4  Yellow  Bike     3      3  Standard
0     Red   Car     3     10  Adjusted
1    Blue  Bike     6      7  Adjusted
2    Blue   Car     4      8  Adjusted
3   Green  Bike     6     27  Adjusted
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) then use [`df.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
df
#   Colour  Type  Cost  Price    Type.1
#0     Red   Car     3      5  Standard
#1    Blue  Bike     6      7  Standard
#2    Blue   Car     4      8  Standard
#3   Green  Bike     6      9  Standard
#4  Yellow  Bike     3      3  Standard
dfs
#  Colour  values
#0    Red       2
#1   Blue       1
#2  Green       3

dfm = dfs.merge(df, on='Colour')
dfm[['Cost','Price']] = dfm[['Cost', 'Price']].mul(dfm['values'] ,axis=0)
dfm['Type.1'] = 'Adjusted'

pd.concat([df,dfm.loc[:,df.columns]])

   Colour  Type  Cost  Price    Type.1
0     Red   Car     3      5  Standard
1    Blue  Bike     6      7  Standard
2    Blue   Car     4      8  Standard
3   Green  Bike     6      9  Standard
4  Yellow  Bike     3      3  Standard
0     Red   Car     6     10  Adjusted
1    Blue  Bike     6      7  Adjusted
2    Blue   Car     4      8  Adjusted
3   Green  Bike    18     27  Adjusted
```

---

If the mapping you have is a series with index as `Colour` then use use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`df.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) or `df._get_numeric_dataPrivate method`

```
dfs # Type `pandas.core.series.Series`
#Colour
#Red      2
#Blue     1
#Green    3
#Name: values, dtype: int64

t = df.copy()
cols = t.select_dtypes(np.int64).columns
t[cols] = t[cols].mul(t['Colour'].map(dfs),axis=0)
t['Type.1'] = 'Adjusted'
pd.concat([df,t.dropna()])

   Colour  Type  Cost  Price    Type.1
0     Red   Car   3.0    5.0  Standard
1    Blue  Bike   6.0    7.0  Standard
2    Blue   Car   4.0    8.0  Standard
3   Green  Bike   6.0    9.0  Standard
4  Yellow  Bike   3.0    3.0  Standard
0     Red   Car   6.0   10.0  Adjusted
1    Blue  Bike   6.0    7.0  Adjusted
2    Blue   Car   4.0    8.0  Adjusted
3   Green  Bike  18.0   27.0  Adjusted
```